# Selecting everything from table 1 with average AND distinct values from table 2 and table 3

Tags: mysql

*I am not entirely sure even how to name this post, because I do not know exactly how to ask it.*

I have three tables. One with users, one with foods and one with the users rating of the foods, like such (simplified example):

```
Foods
id  name    type
---------------------
1   Apple   fruit
2   Banana  fruit
3   Steak   meat

Users
id  username
-----------------
1   Mark
2   Harrison
3   Carrie

Scores (fid = food id, uid = user id)
fid uid score
---------------------
1   1   3
1   2   5
2   1   2
3   2   3
```

Now, I have this query, which works perfectly:

```
SELECT fn.name as Food, ROUND(AVG(s.score),1) AS AvgScore FROM Foods fn LEFT JOIN Scores s ON fn.id = s.fid GROUP BY fn.id ORDER BY fn.name ASC
```

As you can tell, it lists all names from Foods including an average from all users ratings of the food.

I also want to add the unique users own score. (Assume that when Mark is logged in, his uid is set in a session variable or whatever)

I need the following output, if you are logged in as Mark:

```
Food    AvgScore    Your Score
Apple   4           3
```

I have made several attempts to make this happen, but I cannot find the solution. I have learned that if you have a question, it is very likely that someone else has asked it before you do, but I do not quite know how to phrase the question, so I get no answers when googling. A pointer in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `case`:

```
SELECT fn.name as Food, 
       ROUND(AVG(s.score),1) AS AvgScore,
       sum(case s.uid = $uid when s.score else 0 end) as YourScore
FROM Foods fn 
LEFT JOIN Scores s ON fn.id = s.fid 
GROUP BY fn.id 
ORDER BY fn.name ASC
```

`$uid` is variable off course.

Comment: I copied your solution as is, and it gave me an SQL syntax error, but I accept your answer as a solution because it did exactly what I asked for - a pointer in the right direction. I had never seen the "case"-statement before, and after a few tries, I got it to work just as I wanted. Many, many thanks! :)

I changed it from:

`sum(case s.uid = $uid when s.score else 0 end) as YourScore`

to:

`sum(case when s.uid = 2 then s.score else 0 end) as YourScore`

Comment: Welcome. :) Probably you gave the error because of `$uid` is the variable.

Comment: No, I just forgot to change it when I posted the comment. And now I cannot edit the comment anymore because it is too old.